# JSON indentation in PHP

Tags: php, json

I want to echo JSON in with indentation in PHP, just like `echo "<pre>";` indents an array.

Is there any function by which I can indent JSON like this?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From PHP 5.4 onwards, [json_encode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) has a JSON_PRETTY_PRINT flag

```
$pretty=json_encode($foo, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

If you're stuck with an ancient version of PHP, then the manual page for json_encode includes a [user-contributed sample](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php#80339) showing how to pretty-print JSON.

Answer (score 27):

In fact, [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/function.json-encode.php) has an option to do pretty-print in **PHP 5.4**. To use it:

```
<pre>
<?php echo nl2br(json_encode($yourArrayOrObject, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT)); ?>
</pre>
```